# Swift set or update asset in core data

Tags: core-data, copy, mutable, nsset

- Two Entities
- Gymnast is one to many to Meet
- I would like to when I save a new meet, it gets assigned to as a meet to each gymnast where they can then score their individuals scores for each event

Maybe I completely wrong in my logic, but here is what I am trying to do

let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Gymnast")

```
    do {

        let entities = try AD.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Gymnast]

        for item in entities {

            if let first = item.valueForKey("firstName"), last = item.valueForKey("lastName") {

                print("Name: \(first) \(last)")

                let myMeet = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Meet", inManagedObjectContext: AD.managedObjectContext) as! Meet

                myMeet.meetName = "Winter Classic"

                let myMeets = item.meets!.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableSet
                myMeets.addObject(myMeet)

                item.meets = myMeets.copy() as? NSSet

                AD.saveContext()

            }

        }

    } catch {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you want to connect every Gymnast to every Meet, the releationship should be many-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not ideal to replicate the `Meet` object over and over again for each `Gymnast`. For example, the `meetName` will be stored multiple times. I am not sure this is intended.

However, going with your setup, your problem is how you assign the to-many relationship. For a one-to-many it is always easier to simply set the to-one relationship. (Remember, there is always a reverse relationship in the Core Data model.)

Thus,

```
myMeet.gymnast = item
```

is all you need.

To add and remove to-many relationships, you can use this extension:

```
// Support adding to many-to-many relationships

extension NSManagedObject {
    func addObject(value: NSManagedObject, forKey key: String) {
        let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey(key)
        items.addObject(value)
    }

    func removeObject(value: NSManagedObject, forKey key: String) {
        let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey(key)
        items.removeObject(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks both of you for your responses.  I agree and I have changed the relationship to many to many but still am not sure how to save it.

Comment: 2016-03-26 13:36:48.326 GymScore[1111:343330] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value in to-many relationship: property = "gymnasts"; problem = {(
    <GymScore.Meet: 0x14094d3e0> (entity: Meet; id: 0x13f7ac240 <x-coredata:///Meet/tE3B4716B-7B24-4181-8B51-539297CB392F2> ; data: {

Comment: NSValidationErrorKey: gymnasts, NSLocalizedDescription: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)]

Comment: extension Meet {
    func addObject(value: Meet, forKey key: String) {
        let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey(key)
        items.addObject(value)
    }
    
    func removeObject(value: Meet, forKey key: String) {
        let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey(key)
        items.removeObject(value)
    }
}

Comment: if let meetname = meetNameText.text {
                
                item.meetName = meetname

                item.addObject(item, forKey: "meets")